# Icon on MenuItem not Displaying

Tags: c#, wpf, image, mvvm, binding

I have the following menu in my view of my WPF MVVM application

```
<Menu DockPanel.Dock="Top" >
    <MenuItem Header="File">
       <MenuItem Header="Open Video..." 
                         ToolTip="Open Video File..."
                         Caliburn:Message.Attach="[Event Click] = [Action OpenFile()]" 
                         InputGestureText="Ctrl + O">
          <MenuItem.Icon>
             <Image Width="16" Height="16"
                    Source="pack://application:,,,/Redactor;component/Resources/Pngs/open_document_black_16.png"/>
          </MenuItem.Icon>
       </MenuItem>
    </MenuItem>
    <MenuItem Header="Actions" ItemsSource="{Binding DynamMenuItems}">
        <MenuItem.Resources>
            <Image x:Key="FrozenImage" x:Shared="False" Source="{Binding Path=Image}"/>
        </MenuItem.Resources>
        <MenuItem.ItemContainerStyle>
            <Style TargetType="{x:Type MenuItem}" BasedOn="{StaticResource MetroMenuItem}">
                <!--<Setter Property="Icon" Value="{Binding Path=Image}"/>-->
                <Setter Property="Icon" Value="{StaticResource FrozenImage}"/>
                <Setter Property="Header" Value="{Binding Path=Text}"/>
                <Setter Property="Command" Value="{Binding Path=Command}"/>
            </Style>
        </MenuItem.ItemContainerStyle>
    </MenuItem>
</Menu>
```

In the view model I have the following code

```
private void BuildSelectionContextMenuItems()
{
    if (RedactionMenuItems == null)
        RedactionMenuItems = new BindableCollection<ContextMenuItem>();

    RedactionMenuItems.Clear();

    RedactionMenuItems.Add(new ContextMenuItem(
        Utils.GetImageFromUrl("pack://application:,,,/Redactor;component/Resources/Pngs/save_black_16.png"),
        "Save selection to video file...", 
        SaveSelectionToVideoFile));

    RedactionMenuItems.Add(new ContextMenuItem(
        "Commence auto-redaction on the selection...",
        PerformAutoRedactionOnSelection));

    RedactionMenuItems.Add(new ContextMenuItem(
        "Create matching audio-interval for selection",
        CreateAudioIntervalFromSelection));
}

private BindableCollection<ContextMenuItem> redactionMenuItems;
private ICommand saveSelectionToVideoFile;
private ICommand performAutoRedactionOnSelection;
private ICommand createAudioIntervalFromSelection;

public BindableCollection<ContextMenuItem> RedactionMenuItems
{
    get { return redactionMenuItems; }
    set
    {
        redactionMenuItems = value;
        NotifyOfPropertyChange(() => RedactionMenuItems);
    }
}
```

This works and displays the menu items, but the icon does not display, when I change the XAML code to

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type MenuItem}" BasedOn="{StaticResource MetroMenuItem}">
    <Setter Property="Icon" Value="{Binding Path=Image}"/>
    <Setter Property="Header" Value="{Binding Path=Text}"/>
    <Setter Property="Command" Value="{Binding Path=Command}"/>
</Style>
```

It shows once, then disappears. So I try to use the known method to make the icon non-shared using `x:Shared="False"`. But I can't understand why this is not working as I also use the same `RedactionMenuItems` to bind to a `ContextMenu` on a control and this works fine. Why is this code not working?

---

The `ContextMenuItem` class is

```
public class ContextMenuItem : PropertyChangedBase
{
    private Image image;
    private string text;
    private ICommand command;

    public ContextMenuItem(Image image, string text, ICommand command)
    {
        Image = image;
        Text = text;
        Command = command;
    }
    public ContextMenuItem(string text, ICommand command) : this(null, text, command) { }

    public Image Image
    {
        get { return image; }
        set
        {
            image = value;
            NotifyOfPropertyChange(() => Image);
        }
    }

    public string Text
    {
        get { return text; }
        set
        {
            text = value;
            NotifyOfPropertyChange(() => Text);
        }
    }

    public ICommand Command
    {
        get { return command; }
        set
        {
            command = value;
            NotifyOfPropertyChange(() => Command);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This portion of your xaml:

```
<MenuItem.Resources>
    <Image x:Key="FrozenImage" x:Shared="False" Source="{Binding Path=Image}"/>
</MenuItem.Resources>
```

is binding the `Source` property to an `Image` object in your ViewModel. The `Source` property must be bound to an `ImageSource` object.  So, you have 2 solutions:

1. In your ViewModel, change the type of your `Image` property to be of type `ImageSource`.  Note: you will need to create an appropriate `ImageSource` object to return.  I used a `BitmapImage` like so:

   ```
   var image1 = new Image();
   image1.Source = new BitmapImage(new Uri("/Images/print.png", UriKind.Relative));
   ```
2. Create a `Converter` object to convert your image property to an `ImageSource` object.